# How do I break CSS3 gradient evenly?

Tags: html, css

can someone please help me make this gradient break evenly

```
body {
    height: 2500px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000 1%,#FFFFFF 1%,#FFFFFF 13%,#2ecc71 13%,#2ecc71 30%,#3498db 30%,#000000,#FFFFFF,#34495e);
}
```

I've been trying for hours and still can't do it. Always seems to overlap!! Am I using the % properly??? I can get them all on there to blend but when it comes to breaking them even its a nightmare! With my code provided up above I am trying to break the rest just like I had the other color if you compile my code, ty.

Comment: If you are having difficulty but comfortable with creating gradients in something like Photoshop then this generator should feel quite comfortable http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

The code does not looks correct.
You should try some ready generator like http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/

Maybe what you wanted it was (and no you were not using % properly)
See syntax here (http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_gradient-linear_repeating)

```
body
{
    height: 2500px;
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#000000 ,#FFFFFF 1%,#FFFFFF 13%,#2ecc71 26%,#2ecc71 30%,#3498db 35%,#000000 45%,#FFFFFF 45%,#34495e 50%);
}
```

In case you don't want it to repeat.

```
body
{
    height: 2500px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000 ,#FFFFFF 1%,#FFFFFF 13%,#2ecc71 26%,#2ecc71 30%,#3498db 35%,#000000 45%,#FFFFFF 45%,#34495e 50%);
}
```

For even breakup, breakup your percentage evenly. Note that the percentage means that first color is at 0 and then next at 12% so between 0 to 125 of height, the color will move from black to white and then from 12 to 24 % it stays white and then gradient from white to #2ecc71  from 24% to 36% of height...

```
body
{
    height: 2500px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000000 ,#FFFFFF 12%,#FFFFFF 24%,#2ecc71 36%,#2ecc71 48%,#3498db 60%,#000000 72%,#FFFFFF 84%,#34495e 96%);
}
```

PS: WRT to the % it should be noted that all % must be unique and increasing

Comment: appreciate the feedback but I do not want them repeating I want them to break evenly in different sections,

Comment: @bestplayer do you have an image/picture of what exactly do you need?

Comment: @bestplayer I am assuming you want bands of gradients between some colors and you want the bands to be equal in height. Look at the generator link in my answer and that may help you.

Comment: @bestplayer I studied your gradient and it seems that you want to create color bands but the edges are blurring into each other. Is that the problem? I always assumed it to be default browser method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9678H/ take a look at that. I cannot seem to create color bands after the teal. I've tried everything but they still seem to overlap